# Importing changes to existing ads with Google Adwords Editor

Tags: google-ads-api

Google Adwords Editor ver 10.2.1

It is possible to change the ad text for existing ads via the UI?

I would like to make changes by importing a csv file.

I have tried exporting my campaign, editing the csv file and re-importing the file using Adwords Editor. But the changed text is imported as a **new** ad - not a change to the existing ad.

Is it possible to make changes to existing ads using the import functionality?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this has nothing to do with programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In AdWords, it is impossible to change the text of ads, no matter what method you use.

- Editor will create new ads for you.
- You can upload a CSV file into the web interface, and that will generate new ads.
- You can use the "edit" functionality in the UI, and that will still create new ads.

To summarize - nothing you can do :)

Comment: I tested this with the editor and you're absolutely right. Edits to existing ads are uploaded as a deletion of the old ad and creation of the new ad. I never knew this. Thanks. Maybe you have a suggestion for my follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19517184/delete-all-existing-ads-via-import-with-google-adwords-editor

Answer (score 0):

Since AdWords register data for a certain ad you can never have the old data assigned to a new/changed ad since that data wouldn't be correct for that new/changed ad.

Just remove all the old ads and import the new ones.

Comment: Please do not leave Signatures in your answers. You can link to whatever your site is in your profile, and only there.