# Delete all existing ads via import with Google Adwords Editor

Tags: google-ads-api

I want to use Adwords Editor CSV import to **change** the ad text for an ad group.

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506095/importing-changes-to-existing-ads-with-google-adwords-editor/), it is impossible to modify an existing ad. Adwords can only delete existing ads and create new ads. So what I need to do is delete the old ad and insert the new ad.

I have put my new ad in a CSV file and when I import the file, the ad is created correctly. My problem is that the old ad still exists.

Normally I would just mark the old ad in the CSV file with status "deleted" but the problem is, I do not know the text of the old ad. I just want to delete **any** ad that exists so that my new ad effectively replaces the old ad.

Is there an easy way to delete the old ad via the import, even though I don't know the text?

Or maybe someone has a suggestion for another approach to replacing ads en masse?

(Google Adwords Editor ver 10.2.1)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the use of a specific tool/service, not about programming.

Comment: @CBroe: Happy to move it to a different forum but I couldn't find one that is more appropriate. SO has more Adwords tagged questions than any of the other forums I checked (Superuser, Webmaster, Web Applications, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Edit" functionality in the AdWords Web application. It's capable of all kinds of find/replace, and knows to delete your old ads. Look for the "Edit" dropdown on Ads tab.

Comment: Please explain your answer more clearly. I am familiar with the Edit functionality but I can't see how this can be used if I do not know the text of the existing ads.

Comment: oops, forgot about that... yeah, if you don't know what the existing text is, this is indeed a problem :( you can still delete old ads in bulk?